# Flask redirect to URL with variable

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I want to make a redirection to a URL and pass variable 'file' to it , can someone please help . Here is the view :

```
@app.route('/api/uploads/<string:file>/', methods=['GET','COPY']) 
def download(file):
   sub = db.session.query(func.max(Content.Hits).label('max_hit')).subquery()
  contenu = db.session.query(Content).join(sub, sub.c.max_hit == Content.Hits).all()
name1 = contenu[0].name

if name1 == file:
   return redirect('http://192.168.198.134:5000/api/uploads/<string:file>', file)

else:   
    return send_from_directory(UPLOAD_FOLDER, file)
```

Answer (score 8):

This is what the [`url_for()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/api/#flask.url_for) is for:

```
from Flask import url_for

redirect(url_for(download, file=file))
```

`url_for()` takes the endpoint name of your view (by default the name of your function, here `download`), and additional keyword arguments to provide values for the parameters.

Also see the [*URL Building* section](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/latest/quickstart/#url-building) in the Quickstart documentation.

Comment: sorry but the URL points to another flask server running on another machine . i think url_for can be used if i redirect to a page on the same server

Comment: @Rzozi: then use `url_for()` to build the path, and then post-process that URL to set the servername.

Comment: @MartijnPerters : Can i do it like this : 
       return redirect('http://192.168.198.134:5000/ %s' % url_for(download,file=file)

Comment: You'll have to be careful to escape the path element properly. `url_for()` handles this for you already.